# Displaying/Nesting MediaWiki pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, mediawiki, nested

I already googled and tried myself for days now without result. How is it possible to nest MediaWiki in Wordpress (both the latest stable versions)? All I found (and this isn't much) is for old versions of MW and WP. There seems to be no working plugin or tutorial.

Simply including the MW files messes up the html (doctype, etc.).

What basically should be done is:

Use Wordpress header, menu and background for navigation and design and use MediaWiki to display the content.

Is there any not-to-hard way to achieve this?

Comment: Besides the content, which features of mediawiki do you need to make available? For example, login/registration, edit content, view discussion pages?

Comment: MediaWiki should be the content provider and the whole stuff (edit, history, discussion ...) should not be visible to normal website visitors (only to logged in admins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the Wordpress framework (via wp-load.php) into your Mediawiki templates. Follow the instructions here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-mediawiki-integration#post-1742900

Comment: But doesn't this mess up the html? (double doctypes for example)

Comment: I would use the doctype provided by my Wordpress header and remove the doctypes, etc from the MediaWiki templates. You have to modify those templates to add the wp-load.php anyway.

Comment: But I still have the whole sidebar and everything from MediaWiki visible. And I get an error "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by".

Comment: MediaWiki sidebar can be disabled via the theme files or via CSS. The header error I'm not sure about, but it should be a matter of looking to see where MediaWiki is trying to set the headers and adding the wp-load.PHP after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Wordpress so this may be way off but have you considered using an [iFrame](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWebsite_in_iFrame)?

(See also [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716))